# javascript jquery regexp replace

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace

I'm trying to create a dynamic searchbar and i need help.

Right now im trying to replace a string with another string but i cant seem to succeed.

Im getting input from the user:

```
var location_keyword = $("#si_user_location").val();
```

Now i would like to replace a whitespace " " with a "|" to use this in my regexp as OR.

For example if the user wrote "Turkey Alanya", i want it to be "Turkey|Alanya" so that the search hits for both Turkey OR Alanya.

i tried something like this but it didnt work

```
var location_keyword = $("#si_user_location").val();
location_keyword.replace(" ","|");
var regexp_loc = new RegExp(location_keyword, "i");
```

i used to do this in PHP before with expressions such as:

```
preg_replace('/'.preg_quote($keyword).'/i', "<span>$0</span>", $string)
```

and i could replace strings caseinsensetive like this, how can i do this in js?

I used the last expression in PHP to highlight the keyword in the results, which i would like to do aswell in js.

hope i can get some help, thanks in advance! :)

best of regards,
alexander

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems with the use of [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) on this line:

```
location_keyword.replace(" ","|");
```

- It does not modify the string - it returns a new string. You need to reassign the result of the call to the original variable otherwise you won't see the changed string.
- It only replaces the first occurrence unless you use a regular expression with the `g` (global) flag.

Try this instead:

```
location_keyword = location_keyword.replace(/ /g, '|');
```

Comment: what is the /g in the regexp ?

Comment: /g stands for global, meaning replace all instances of the needle in haystack, instead of only replacing just the first instance you find.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
location_keyword  = location_keyword.replace(/\s+/,"|");
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine:

```
location_keyword.replace(/ /g,"|");
```

Hope this helps! :)