# Converting php regexp to JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, regex, replace

I'm trying to convert the following php expression into JavaScript but I'm having trouble with one thing.

```
preg_replace('/'.preg_quote($keyword).'/i', "<span>$0</span>", $string)
```

What happens here is that I can reuse the found substring with the right "case letters". Its hard to explain what I mean but let me give an example:

If the user inputs sweden, then this string is all lowercase letters. But in the result this same word is written as Sweden, so I want it to keep its cases as they are.

it is possible to do this in php by using the matched value $0, as you can see in the php expression.

In JavaScript what I have so far is:

```
var highlighted_sub = location_sub_name[i].replace(regexp_highlight,"<span class='loc_keyword'>" + location_keyword + "</span>");
```

This replaces the original result with the input from the user, so I get sweden in all lower case letters as the user input them, when I actually want the cases to be as they really are.

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript jquery regexp replace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5172816/javascript-jquery-regexp-replace)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the same in javascript; the only exception is that the "entire match" backreference is `$&` instead of `$0`. The rest, `$1` through `$9`, works exactly the same though. Try it out in the address bar of your browser:

```
javascript: document.write('foobar'.replace(/(f)[o]/g, ' $1 $& '));
```

This page has more info: http://www.regular-expressions.info/refreplace.html